# How I can replace part of the src of 8 images on click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, toggle, swiper.js

I have a slider with 8 images with a common folder in its source (`img/banana/#.png`, `img/strawberry/#.png` or `img/apple/#.png`) that I need to change each time I click on another image out of the slider; it also has a folder with a fruit as a name (banana, strawberry or apple). To add one more level of difficulty, I need the image that works as a changing images on slider, also change part of its `src` for the one it changes.

So, if the changing image that I clicked has the src `img/strawberry/1.png` and changes the src of the 8 images that has `img/banana/#.png` as src, it has to be replaced by `img/banana/1.png` and the 8 images with `img/banana/#.png` have to change to `img/strawberry/#.png`. The problem is that I will always have two changing images, and I need to detect the source that the 8 images of the slider have, so they can be replaced by the one of the changing image that is clicked.

This is the code if the slider has 8 images of bananas.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/banana/1.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/banana/2.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/banana/3.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/banana/4.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/banana/5.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/banana/6.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/banana/7.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/banana/8.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <img src="img/frutilla/1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <img src="img/apple/1.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the result that I seek to obtain if I click on one of the two changing images.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/strawberry/1.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/strawberry/2.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/strawberry/3.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/strawberry/4.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/strawberry/5.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/strawberry/6.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/strawberry/7.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="img/strawberry/8.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <img src="img/banana/1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <img src="img/apple/1.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the number on the images are always kept, just change the name of the folder (strawberry, banana or apple). I leave an example in image for reference, so it can be understood better.

[image: example]

Btw, the slider I am using is [SwiperJS](https://swiperjs.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to re-create your project so here is an example that might can help you! Click on the small images under the swiper to change the swiper image URL according to the image you clicked on before.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5qbsz6f7/3/)

***HTML***

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<!-- https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg ## strawberry-->
<!-- https://i.imgur.com/GBDX2ps.jpg ## banana-->

<body>
  <div class="swiper-container mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img data-type="strawberry" src='https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg'></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img data-type="strawberry" src='https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg'></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img data-type="strawberry" src='https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg'></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img data-type="strawberry" src='https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg'></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img data-type="strawberry" src='https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg'></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img data-type="strawberry" src='https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg'></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img data-type="strawberry" src='https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg'></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img data-type="strawberry" src='https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg'></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img data-type="strawberry" src='https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='selector'>
    <img data-type="strawberry" src='https://i.imgur.com/8nKVc0s.jpg'>
    <img data-type="banana" src='https://i.imgur.com/GBDX2ps.jpg'>
  </div>
</body>
```

***JQUERY***

```
$().ready(() => {
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
    },
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selector img').click(function() {
            var iType = $(this).data("type") 
          //I don't have strawberry and banana in URL so in your case you can use the following to get the type
          /*
            var iType = getTypeFromURL($(this).attr("src"))
          */
            
          //Now you go through the images to check their type (or in your case, the URL)
          var curr_selection = $(".swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide img").data("type")
              if (curr_selection != iType) 
          {
            //if the clicked type AND the current images are not fit (by type) then let's change to swiper img urls
            var selectedURL = $(this).attr("src");
            $(".swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide img").each(function(){
                $(this).attr("src", selectedURL).data("type", iType) //you don't need the .data()
            })
          }
        });
    });
})

//In order not to write the logic again and again here is a function that will tell you the type from the URL you give as parameter
function getTypeFromURL(url)
{
    if (url.contains("strawberry")) return "strawberry";
  else if (url.contains("banana")) return "banana";
}
```

Comment: This works but unfortunately there are two problems. I have three fruits, once I click on one of the two of below, I cannot recover the one that was active. I need the one that was active, be deactivated and located at the bottom instead of the one that is activated now. And the second problem is that it replaces with the same src in all 8 images. [Here](http://www.kilimanjjjaro.com/stackoverflow/) I have a real demo with your code, so you can see how it works (the slider is only visible on the mobile width)

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/o609Ld4p/12/) is another modified fiddle that might can help you. I don't fully understand what should be the final output so if you check this version out, please let me your opinions. In this version I implemented an active state that shows you which element is currently active right now and getting disabled.

Comment: Yeah, it works. And thanks to that "active" tag, I can hide it with CSS. Because originally I only have two buttons deactivated and one activated in the slider (with 8 images with different sources). Btw, they keep being replaced by the same src, is there any way to make it replace only the folder and not the whole src? Example, if I click on strawberry (src: img/strawberry/1.png) and banana is activated with its 8 images (src:img/banana/#.png), can I replace only the name of the folder (img/banana/ to img/strawberry)?

Comment: I tried with attr("src") but I couldn't get it work, sorry!

Comment: Yep, you can replace only a given part of the source like this: `$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("banana", "strawberry") )` - this will replace the "banana" to "strawberry" in the current source.